# Angular universal : Unable to prerendering dynamic routes

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular12, angular-seo

There is an issue with prerendering dynamic routes. In my case, product-category is a primary route, and there is a title as a parameter so my link should be **product-category/:title**. There are many categories under my primary route, so I need this dynamic prerendering. How to set this type of data under prerender -> options -> routes or how to dynamic prerendering achieved.

Here is my prerender code under angular.json

```html
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/",
              "/product-category/"
            ]
          },
```

**angular.json**

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "seasonsIndia": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/seasonsIndia/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "crypto-js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss",
              "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/theme.scss"          
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "800kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "seasonsIndia:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "seasonsIndia:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "seasonsIndia:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/seasonsIndia/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "seasonsIndia:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "seasonsIndia:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "seasonsIndia:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "seasonsIndia:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/",
              "/product-category/*"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "seasonsIndia:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "seasonsIndia:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "seasonsIndia:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "seasonsIndia:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "seasonsIndia"
}
```

**server.ts**

```html
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { NgxRequest, NgxResponse } from '@gorniv/ngx-universal';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import * as cookieparser from 'cookie-parser';
import { exit } from 'process';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';

// for debug
require('source-map-support').install();

// for tests
const test = process.env['TEST'] === 'true';

// ssr DOM
const domino = require('domino');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
// index from browser build!
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/seasonsIndia/browser');
const template = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
// const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
// for mock global window by domino
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
// mock
global['window'] = win;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

// not implemented property and functions
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
// mock documnet
global['document'] = win.document;
// othres mock
// global['CSS'] = null;
// global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
// global['Prism'] = null;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
    ? 'index.original.html'
    : 'index';

  // redirects!
  const redirectowww = false;
  const redirectohttps = false;
  const wwwredirecto = true;
  server.use((req, res, next) => {
    // for domain/index.html
    if (req.url === '/index.html') {
      res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname);
    }

    // check if it is a secure (https) request
    // if not redirect to the equivalent https url
    if (
      redirectohttps &&
      req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https' &&
      req.hostname !== 'localhost'
    ) {
      // special for robots.txt
      if (req.url === '/robots.txt') {
        next();
        return;
      }
      res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
    }

    // www or not
    if (redirectowww && !req.hostname.startsWith('www.')) {
      res.redirect(301, 'https://www.' + req.hostname + req.url);
    }

    // www or not
    if (wwwredirecto && req.hostname.startsWith('www.')) {
      const host = req.hostname.slice(4, req.hostname.length);
      res.redirect(301, 'https://' + host + req.url);
    }

    // for test
    if (test && req.url === '/test/exit') {
      res.send('exit');
      exit(0);
    }

    next();
  });

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine(
    'html',
    ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    }),
  );

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(distFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y',
    }),
  );

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    global['navigator'] = { userAgent: req['headers']['user-agent'] } as Navigator;
    const http =
      req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === undefined ? 'http' : req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];

    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },

        // for http and cookies
        {
          provide: REQUEST,
          useValue: req,
        },
        {
          provide: RESPONSE,
          useValue: res,
        },
        /// for cookie
        {
          provide: NgxRequest,
          useValue: req,
        },
        {
          provide: NgxResponse,
          useValue: res,
        },
        // for absolute path
        {
          provide: 'ORIGIN_URL',
          useValue: `${http}://${req.headers.host}`,
        },
      ],
    });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  // gzip
  server.use(compression());
  // cokies
  server.use(cookieparser());

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            "routes": [
              "/",
              "/product-category/*"
            ]
```

There's a clear problem with that code. You're basically asking Angular to guess all possible parameters, titles in your case.

You'd have to be more explicit than that and add the exact routes. See the example in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/prerendering)

```
ng run <app-name>:prerender --routes /product/1 /product/2
```

In your case:

```
 "routes": [
              "/",
              "/product-category/1",
              "/product-category/2",
              ...
            ]
```

If you have a lot of routes, you can always add them in a text file, like this:

```
      // You can place the file wherever you want, 
      // I put it in the src folder, I don't know if there's a 
      // recommended location

        "prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "routesFile":"./src/routes.txt"
      },
```